# Android devices with Google APIs

Tags: android, api

I know this question may be lame, but I'm trying to find a list of Google API supported Android devices. I just want to know how my app compatibility for certain smartphones will look like. Any ideas?

Comment: Doesn't all Android devices support the Google API..?

Comment: Nope. For example Sony-Ericssons Xperias have their own API.

Comment: List of Android phones by supported Google API level?

Comment: @AndroidHustle No, only the ones that have the "with Google(TM)" branding. Some devices don't have Market access or Google apps installed.

Comment: So, any ideas where I can find what I need? Using Google :) didn't help me much.

Comment: @onik Ahh... Yea, that's true... I'd forgotten about that... thanks.

Comment: Sony-Ericssons Xperia has additional APIs but all the normal Android APIs can be used. Normally the google APIs to me would mean devices that have google market installed and can work with the google maps framework. Naturally all devices that are listed in the Google Market will comply to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I realized there is some kind of walkaround solution. You can upload your app on Android Market, save the needed data (screenshots, app name etc.) and activate it (**NOT** publish) and then in app info, just below the list of countries you support, there is a detailed information about devices on which the app should run (and not). I don't know if it works 100% properly, but sure it gives a little bit of help.

Answer (score -1):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Android_devices

Phones that do have or will be getting Gingerbread (might be out of date now?)
http://www.gottabemobile.com/2011/04/21/ultimate-android-2-3-update-list-will-your-phone-be-getting-gingerbread/

Comment: These lists don't differentiate between devices that have Google API and those that don't.

Comment: Well, this doesn't help me much. I'm not interested in overall information about Android versions on certain smartphones, I'm focusing on devices with Google APIs.